# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fr/styygital/jmdesktoplib/GuiDrawer

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, operating-system, virtual

I was making a virtual command-lines OS with ANSI Colors/Gui in Java. I'm using a custom library i make for the Desktop, Colors & Gui and probably more. I have the JMasterDev (my virtual os project) and i wrote :

```
GuiDrawer.drawGui();
```

because my library (JMDesktopLib) contains a class named GuiDrawer which contains a method named drawGui which basically draw the gui with ansi colors.

But, when i exported my library, imported it into my virtual os project, exported my virtual os project (JMasterDev) as JAR File, and i executed this command in windows 10 command prompt :

```
java -cp JMasterDev.jar fr.styygital.jmasterdev.Desktop
```

it shows me this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
fr/styygital/jmdesktoplib/GuiDrawer
        at fr.styygital.jmasterdev.Desktop.main(Desktop.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.styygital.jmdesktoplib.GuiDrawer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

The jar file was on the folder where i executed CMD, so I don't understand this problem.

I tried some methods i found, but none worked.
Can anyone help me with this annoying problem?

PS : I tried to debug the project on Eclipse and it worked.

Comment: Does `JMasterDev.jar` have a `fr/styygital/jmdesktoplib/GuiDrawer.class` file in it?

Comment: no, the GuiDrawer.class is in the JMDesktopLib library.

Comment: How is the class file supposed to be found at runtime, then?

Comment: on the Desktop.class class in JMasterDev project, i wrote GuiDrawer.drawGui(); which is a function in my GuiDrawer.class class. And Desktop.class is my main method for JMasterDev project.

Comment: Where is it at runtime? Exactly what is "JMDesktopLib library" in terms of jar files and where it's located?

Comment: the JMDesktopLib library is for me, it contains the GuiDrawer, the DesktopDrawer, the ANSI Colors and more... and it's located on a folder named JMasterOS/libs/JMDesktopLib.jar.